# sequence contains more than one element code first add-migration

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first

The below is the entity, when I am going to add-migration, it is giving me exception.

```
public class MyEntity
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }


[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase DiagramFMCDocumentUpload { get; set; }
//[ForeignKey("DiagramFMCDocumentID")]
//public Document DiagramFMCDocument { get; set; }
//public int? DiagramFMCDocumentID { get; set; }

//[NotMapped]
//public HttpPostedFileBase ExecutedDeedDocumentUpload { get; set; }

public Document ExecutedDeedDocument { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ExecutedDeedDocument")]
[InverseProperty("ExecutedDeedDocument")]
public int? ExecutedDeedDocumentID { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase DCertificationDocumentUpload { get; set; }

public Document DCertificationDocument { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DCertificationDocument")]
[InverseProperty("DCertificationDocument")]
public int? DCertificationDocumentID { get; set; }

////ForeignFundBasicType
//public int ForeignFundStructureTypeFDID { get; set; }
```

}

When I am commenting out some Document & FOreignKey fields, it perfects fine but more than one foreign key it is not working fine. Here's the exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass293.<>c__DisplayClass295.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__28b(String c)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass293.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__28a(<>f__AnonymousType30`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier286)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains more than one element
PM> Add-Migration First -Force
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass293.<>c__DisplayClass295.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__28b(String c)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass293.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__28a(<>f__AnonymousType30`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier286)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

Comment: Check the first two rows :

       at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass293.<>c__DisplayClass295.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__28b(String c)

Especially that "FindRenamedIndexes" returns more then one element. What was the previous state of your entities?

Answer (score 2):

What is the version of EF you use? I guess that you are using a version earlier than 6.1.3

according to this [issue](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2433), I think updating 'Entity Framework' will fix your problem